# Getting Error "Timed out waiting for debug server to connect" when trying to attach VSCode debugger to a process ID

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, attach-to-process

I am trying to debug a Python code with an attach to process id in VSCode but I'm having an error stating "Timed out waiting for debug server to attach". I usually perform this in Visual Studio Community by the following mean (Headsup, I'm not expert. I'm just trying to reproduce a workflow from Visual Studio to VSCode).
In Visual Studio, this is what I usually do:
[image]

Am I missing anything? I have the latest version of VSCode and I'm using Anaconda's Python as my default Python.

Are there any additional steps I need to do, for example in the Launch.json file, to match the behavior of Visual Studio? To note, I haven't changed anything in the default Launch.json file in VSCode.

Thank you,